# ClearCase - Activity not baselined

Tags: clearcase, baseline

I have been taught that when you create an activity based baseline the selected activities are baselined and the newest version of all the other files in the vob are baselined. When I baselined the other day I found that this did not happen. Two files had version 2 baselined again, not version 3. Versions 2 and 3 are different.

To create the baseline I use a similar command as:

```
mkbl -c "This is my comment" -activities Activity@/vobs/46002913/46002913_pvob 
-full -view 46002913_ucmview_int BaselineId
```

Is what I was taught wrong or am I using a malformed command?

Comment: Can you please provide some refernce to the statement you make about baseline creation. What the CC man page of mkbl says about 
-activities option is "You can use this option to include only a subset of the unrecorded changes in the new baselines. A baseline is created for each component that has unrecorded changes in the specified list of activities". No where it says how versions of element not referred by the activities is handled. Or do I miss anything here ?

Answer (score 0):

One scenario explaining this would be the versions 3 were not visible in the view used to make said baseline.

As mentioned in the [**`mkbl`** man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm):

> Before creating the baseline, be sure that the label is unlocked and ordinary (not global) and that labeled elements are checked in. Once the baseline is created, the label cannot be moved or removed except by privileged users.
>   **Be certain the label selects some version of all visible elements.**

- Either the versions 3 were created just after the baseline (their date can be compared to the one of the baseline), maybe because they were checked-out (in some other view or even in `46002913_ucmview_int` view), and checked-in later.
- Or they were not visible for some reason (custom config spec)